# IntelliJ disable warnings

Tags: actionscript, intellij-idea

IntelliJ displays yellow markers in the scrollbar on the right for warnings. Is there a way to disable warnings or just the yellow markers in the scrollbar?

**Follow-up**: The file in question is from Adobe Flex SDK 4.1 `frameworks/projects/framework/src/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.as`. I have all inspections disabled. I've also disabled the JavaScript Intention Power Pack plugin. I have Highlighting Level set to None. With all this I still see warnings.

[image]

Comment: See my answer to your other (very similar) question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111027/intellij-disable-code-analysis-light-bulb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have concluded that this is a bug in IntelliJ 10.5.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't disable all warnings -- they are there for a purpose.

You can right-click on the yellow warning marker -> "Customize Highlighting Level" -> "Configure Inspections" to tune the severity or turn off particular warnings...

Comment: I am using IntelliJ to browse through the Adobe Flex SDK, which is filled with warnings. I don't care about nor want to see the warnings in my editor. I created a new inspection profile with everything unchecked. This works for the most part, but there are still a few warnings left over. Is there a setting to just disable warnings all together, rather than having to create a separate profile and manually uncheck all warning types?

Comment: @steve so use the right click -> customize highlighting level and adjust the slide bar.

Comment: That's the first thing I tried, I moved it to the far left and it still has a few warnings leftover. I beginning to think this must be an IntelliJ bug. I'm running 10.5.1.