# IntelliJ disable code analysis (light bulb)

Tags: actionscript, intellij-idea

Is there a way to disable code analysis (the light bulb) in IntelliJ? I really don't care about code improvement suggestions as I'm viewing some third party code. I've already unchecked everything single feature in Project Settings -> Inspections.

I'm using IntelliJ 10.5 to edit ActionScript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have concluded that it's not possible to completely disable Inspections in IntelliJ 10.5 (at least while editing ActionScript) possibly due to a bug.

Follow-up: IntelliJ support is saying this may be a bug.

**Edit April 2017**: Finally there is a [workaround](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-94381#comment=27-565622), in particular add:

```
<option name="SHOW_INTENTION_BULB" value="false" />
```

to `IdeaIC2017.1/options/editor.xml`. If there's no `editor.xml` then create a new one as such:

```
<application>
  <component name="EditorSettings">
    <option name="SHOW_INTENTION_BULB" value="false" />
  </component>
</application>
```

Comment: There is an option in Settings to disable the bulb, as answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46770099/785985

Answer (score 14):

On the status bar, there is a little icon showing a man. If you click on it, you can change the inspection level: nothing, syntax, full analysis.

Comment: I have "Highlighting Level" set to "None" and it still shows some light bulbs (Create Setter for). I've seen the same problem with warnings - setting the slider to None still shows some warnings. My only guess is that it's a bug in IntelliJ. See my how to disable warnings question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110460/intellij-disable-warnings

Comment: This only affects the particular intention which is causing the highlighting. The same line (or even variable) may have several things 'wrong' with it.

Comment: So I have the light bulb selected, then I go to little man and Highlighting Level is still set to None. Is there someway to just disable this "feature" all together?

Comment: This is the best answer i found in this topic.

Answer (score 3):

**To disable inspections:**

Settings > Project Settings > Inspections

Click the 'Reset to empty' icon (looks like an eraser)

**To disable intentions:**

Settings > IDE Settings > Intentions

Uncheck *all* of the boxes here

Comment: It still shows warnings (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110460/intellij-disable-warnings) but the intentions are truly disabled.

Comment: Try closing IntelliJ and re-opening it after you make the changes to these settings. They may be cached.   If they still appear, can you provide an example of a warning it shows?

Comment: "Incorrect parameter name" on Flex's ListBase (ActionScript file in Flex SDK 4.1 frameworks/projects/framework/src/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.as). It's warning that the ASDoc (similar to JavaDoc) parameter name doesn't match the actual method signature.

Comment: maybe similar, but in Java classes, it warns "Cannot resolve symbol" for unresolved references inside a javadoc. But this is an Inspection under Javadoc issues.  Do you have an ASDoc issues inspection?

Comment: There is no ASDoc inspection. However, ActionScript seems to be lumped in with JavaScript support. I found and disabled "JavaScript Intention Power Pack" in Plugins but it still gives me warnings.

Comment: Close / reopen / synchronize the file each time, just to make sure it's reinspecting. Also, try searching for 'Incorrect parameter name' in the Intentions and Inspections dialogs. I do not have such a warning, but I also do not have "JavaScript Intention Power Pack"

Comment: Parameter names are also governed by the code style settings. Maybe something is still off there.

Comment: I still get random light bulbs, probably related to the warnings that can't be disabled. I am convinced IntelliJ is buggy.

Comment: and without details, no one here will be able to help. what warnings are still displayed?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for "Intentions", not "Inspections", though I don't know a way to turn them of globally.