# hide Intellij Idea yellow light bulb

Tags: intellij-idea, inspection

Is there a way to hide yellow light bulb, which greatly annoys me showing on every line.
I don't want to disable any inspections. I just want to hide yellow light bulb.

I'm trying to switch from eclipse (not the first time) and this is one of the thing that annoys me greatly and prevent from switching.

I know that I can make refactoring using alt+enter, why remind me constantly about it?

Comment: :( I have recently made the switch (successfully!) from Eclipse .. and the bulb had not annoyed me unitl I read this post :(. Also, related question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111027/intellij-disable-code-analysis-light-bulb

Comment: I discovered that there is an option to disable the lightbulb. And I do not agree with CrazyCoder's answer as I've been working with IntelliJ IDEA since version 9 and the behavior of the lightbulb icon still annoys me multiple times per day. Let this be the last day …

Answer (score 36):

There is an option, but it's not exposed in the preferences dialog. Add or modify the following line inside the `<component name="EditorSettings">` section in your `editor.xml` file and restart IntelliJ IDEA:

```
<option name="SHOW_INTENTION_BULB" value="false" />
```

The file is located at:

- On OS X: `~/Library/Preferences/<PRODUCT>/options/editor.xml`
- On Windows: `%HOMEPATH%\.<PRODUCT>\config\options\editor.xml`
- On Linux: `~/.<PRODUCT>/config/options/editor.xml`

where `<PRODUCT>` is e.g. `IdeaIC13`, `IntelliJIdea13`, `PyCharm30` or `AndroidStudio`.

This will prevent the lightbulb from ever being shown. This solution came up in [the discussion](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-94381) of an issue about this problem.

Comment: +1 Good find.  I just started using intellij, and the bulb was an instant annoyance.  On Windows, I found this file at `C:\Users\YOURNAME\.IdeaIC13\config\options\editor.xml` .  Change the bulb option from "true" to "false".

Comment: @icy Thanks! I've added the file location on Windows to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for that tidbit. The bulb is an annoyance as it is currently implemented since to select text you have to click multiple times to get around the bulb.

Comment: Thanks for saving WebStorm from an early death on my machine... awful UX decision. For those using WebStorm, the <PRODUCT> from the above Windows path is WebIde80.

Comment: What section of the XML file should this go?  Should it be under the XmlEditorOptions component or at the top level?

Comment: @ScottBiggs In section `EditorSettings`. I updated the answer.

Comment: FYI: This works as advertised for WebStorm 2016.2.4.

Comment: Thanks for freeing me from this annoyance.  This also works for Android Studio.  The file location is:  `C:\Users\user-name\.AndroidStudio2.2\config\options\editor.xml`.

Comment: If you have version controlled settings you need to make this change in the repository rather than in the local file otherwise it gets removed every time you start up.

Answer (score 11):

The option is now available in the Settings! Rejoice!

```
Editor > General > Appearance
[ ] Show intention bulb
```

If you don't see the option there, type "bulb" in the search box within Settings and look through the results.

Comment: This is still valid in the current version (2023.1.3), in the same location too (Editor, General, Appearance).