# Disable PyCharm's light bulbs while keeping intentions available?

Tags: pycharm

I like PyCharm's intentions *when* I want them, not when they are constantly popping up via the light bulb to distract me.

Is there a way to disable the light bulbs but have the intentions still available as normal via Alt-Enter?

Note [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712626/hide-intellij-idea-yellow-light-bulb) shows an **editor.xml** config option for IntelliJ to hide the light bulb. PyCharm is based on IntelliJ but I can't find any such XML config file in my installation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Figured it out:

1. Find **editor.xml** in the ~/Library/Preferences/PyCharm30/options folder
2. Add the line `<option name="SHOW_INTENTION_BULB" value="false" />`
3. Restart
4. Rejoice in best of both worlds -- less distraction but inspections/intentions still available with Alt-Enter

Comment: Thank you! One other thing that distracts me in pycharm is waved lines for errors, they are so ugly. I know how to change that but there are not many options.

Comment: In the 2016 version of Pycharm, the structure of the configuration files changed, I'm having trouble matching it to the above solution.

Comment: @Ant6n: The file is `~/Library/Preferences/PyCharm2016.1/options/editor.xml`. I just changed mine now.

Comment: If you have version controlled settings you need to make this change in the repository rather than in the local file otherwise it gets removed every time you start up.

Comment: In 2019+ there's a setting for this, as described [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54925739).

Answer (score 8):

**Update in 2019:**

There is now a setting for this in the `File > Settings...`:

Under `Editor > General > Appearance` uncheck the option `Show intention bulb`.

Comment: Thank you!!! Not sure JetBrains make this thing so obtrusive? Sometimes I literally couldn't get at something, eg, like highlight a line of code because the intention light bulb (providing no value to me, BTW) was in the way. I'd have to click a few characters away then keyboard left arrow to get there. Ugh.

Answer (score 1):

@Ghopper21's answer worked for me. Here's how my `editor.xml` looked after I applied the fix.

```
<application>
  <component name="EditorSettings">
    <option name="ARE_LINE_NUMBERS_SHOWN" value="true" />
    <option name="SHOW_INTENTION_BULB" value="false" />
  </component>
</application>
```

In PyCharm 4.5, the path to my editor.xml file was `~/Library/Preferences/PyCharm40/options`

Answer (score 0):

**Adding an update for 2017:**

In Python Community Edition version 2017.2.3 for Windows I found the **editor.xml** file instead in `C:\Users\<username>\.PyCharmCE2017.2\config\options`

Answer (score 0):

For Windows in 2020 and PyCharm community edition:

@Ghopper21's xml file may be located here:

C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2020.1\options

Another option, in PyCharm IDE:

File -> Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> Python

Then deselect everything.

This illustrious lightbulb issue may have me moving back to Anaconda's Spyder or EMACS

Comment: actually, the above still doesn't hide the lightbulb. any suggestions for windows 10 + PyCharm community edition 2020.1?