# Disable lightbulb in Android Studio's Java editor

Tags: java, android, configuration, android-studio

I just installed Android Studio and have begun the process of configuring the editor to my taste. However, I cannot for the life of me find an option to disable the little light bulb that appears in the left margin a second after clicking a line of text.

[edit] I've only noticed this in the java editor, so I edited the subject line to help indicate that.

Does anyone know how this feature can be disabled?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hide Intellij Idea yellow light bulb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712626/hide-intellij-idea-yellow-light-bulb)

Comment: @RalphBergmann This question is about android-studio whilst the other one is about intellij.

Comment: @Seth Android Studio is based on IntelliJ ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712626/hide-intellij-idea-yellow-light-bulb).  Basically, to disable the feature you have to manually edit the editor.xml and change `SHOW_INTENTION_BULB` from `true` to `false`.  The editor settings are located here:

The file is located at:

- On OS X: `~/Library/Preferences/<PRODUCT>/options/editor.xml`
- On Windows: `%HOMEPATH%\.<PRODUCT>\config\options\editor.xml`
- On Linux: `~/.<PRODUCT>/config/options/editor.xml`

<PRODUCT> for me was AndroidStudio.

Comment: Worked for me, too, thanks!  Note that as you upgrade, you'll see other directories: AndroidStudio, AndroidStudio1.2, AndroidStudio1.3, etc.  Just use the first directory without the numbers.

Comment: But a day later, it's back!  I checked the editor.xml file, and it still has SHOW_INTENTION_BULB set to false.  Sigh.

Comment: Is there still working ? I can't found neither editor.xml nor `bulb` keywords in latest Android Studio Linux.

Comment: Show intention bulb is now a field in preferences. No need to edit the xml anymore

Answer (score 1):

These are called "Intentions" in Android Studio. You can either disable them one at a time or groups of them. The settings can be found in:

File > Settings > Editor > Intentions

I personally don't like any helpers of any kind when developing. I simply unchecked everything and clicked OK.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I actually haven't used Android Studio for quite some time as the project I was working on was unfortunately short-lived.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way so far:
In the Settings of Android Studio search for "bulb".
You'll find "Show intention bulb" check-box.