# disable all intention bulbs intellij 2016.1

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way to completely turn off all intentions light bulbs in Intellij 2016.1, so that none ever appear? In older versions, you could apparently edit options/editor.xml, but no such file exists in 2016.1.

Comment: At this point I find them more distracting than useful - maybe that'll change.

Comment: @duffymo Because, for example, I'm doing a presentation or a screen cast and I don't want distracting stuff such as intention light bulbs to appear. (Even in IntelliJ's presentation mode they appear).

Answer (score 5):

I just answered that in [hide Intellij Idea yellow light bulb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712626/hide-intellij-idea-yellow-light-bulb/46770099)

TL;DR:

```
Preferences > Appearance > Show intention bulb
```

Update:

In GoLand 2020.1 (and possibly all InteliJ 2020.1 products) this setting can be found here:

```
Editor > General > Appearance > Show intention bulb
```

If that doesn't work for you, type "bulb" in the search field in the Settings. I hope that helps.

Comment: The Show Intention bulb checkbox doesn't seem to appear for Windows 10 PyCharmCE 2020.1 -- any workarounds?

Comment: I updated the answer according to what I see in my GoLand 2020.1 on Mac. I hope it translates to your environment as well. Typing "bulb" in the search field should definitely do the trick - one of the best things about InteliJ's settings system is that it's entirely searchable.

Comment: thanks! in my case: File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance -> Show intention bulb

Comment: In IntelliJ 2023.3.2, it's the same as described in Ivaylo's 2020 update: go to Editor > General > Appearance, then find the "Show intention bulb" checkbox and uncheck it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/configuring-intention-actions.html?origin=old_help

To configure intention settings using the Settings dialog

By default, all available intention actions that ship with IntelliJ IDEA, are enabled. By changing the Intention Settings, you can disable the actions that are not required for your current working environment.

Open the Settings / Preferences Dialog by choosing File | Settings for Windows and Linux or IntelliJ IDEA | Preferences for OS X, and click Intentions under Editor.
In the Intentions page, clear the check boxes of the intention actions or action categories that you do not currently need.
Selecting or clearing a category affects all intention actions in this category.
Apply changes and close the dialog.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried unchecking every intentions box, but I still get some intention bulbs (maybe mostly constructor-related).